# What is an architecturally clean way to omit fields from a database response in an API using Typescript and Kysely

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Kysely and Typescript. I can get a User model response by doing:

```
interface User {
  id: Generated<number>
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  password: string
  is_email_verified: boolean
  role: 'admin' | 'user'
}

interface Database {
  user: User
}

dbClient = dbClient || new Kysely<Database>({
  dialect: new PlanetScaleDialect({url: config.mysql.url})
})

const getUserById = async (id: number) => {
  const user = await db
    .selectFrom('user')
    .selectAll()
    .where('user.id', '=', id)
    .executeTakeFirst()
  return user
}
```

My API will get the reponse object like so:

```
const getUser: Handler<{ Bindings: Bindings }> = async (c) => {
  const { params } = userValidation.getUser.parse(c.req.parseBody());
  const user = await userService.getUserById(params.userId);
  if (!user) {
    throw new ApiError(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 'User not found');
  }
  return c.json(user, httpStatus.OK as StatusCode);
};
```

I will do something like the above for all my models/tables. The issue I have is some of these models will have non public fields e.g. password on User. What is the best way to omit these?

I could do a `userReponse` function e.g. in `user.model.ts`:

```
interface User {
  id: Generated<number>
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  password: string
  is_email_verified: boolean
  role: 'admin' | 'user'
}

interface UserResponse {
  id: number
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  is_email_verified: boolean
  role: 'admin' | 'user'
}

const userResponse = (body: Selectable<User>) => {
  return {
    id: body.id,
    first_name: body.first_name,
    last_name: body.last_name,
    email: body.email,
    is_email_verified: body.is_email_verified,
    role: body.role
  } as UserResponse
}

export {
  User,
  UserResponse,
  userResponse
}
```

Then do:

```
return c.json(userResponse(user), httpStatus.OK as StatusCode);
```

Or I could create a UserResponse class with a list of private fields that implements the User interface and overrides the `toJSON()` method removing any fields that are included in the private members array. But somehow this feels wrong as Kysely gives me a User class out of the box returned from the DB query. Unless I convert the Kysely response to my own model on every query so e.g.

```
const getUserById = async (id: number) => {
  const user = await db
    .selectFrom('user')
    .selectAll()
    .where('user.id', '=', id)
    .executeTakeFirst()
  return UserModel(user)
}
```

Any idea on what the clean/optimal solution is?

Comment: `Omit` is built-in: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys

Comment: @zenly You're right, but this is irrelevant to the question being asked. OP wants to omit sensitive keys from runtime (not compile-time) JSON objects before sending them back to client.

Answer (score 2):

[Kysely](https://kysely.dev) is a query builder, not an ORM. It only has compile-time (not runtime) knowledge of your schema.

---

You could keep a list of the table's column names at runtime and pass only non-sensitive ones to `.select(keys)` / `.returning(keys)` instead of using `.selectAll()` / `.returningAll()`. You also benefit from fetching only the data that you need.

```js
const nonSensitiveUserColumns = [
  "id",
  "first_name",
  "last_name",
  "email",
  "role",
] as const satisfies ReadonlyArray<keyof User>

const getUserById = async (id: number) => {
  const user = await db
    .selectFrom("user")
    .where("user.id", "=", id)
    .select(nonSensitiveUserColumns)
    .executeTakeFirst()
  return user
}

const user = await getUserById(15)
//      ^? { id: number; first_name: string; last_name: string; email: string; role: 'admin' | 'user' }
```

[Playground Link](https://kyse.link/?p=b&i=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_IHsgaWQ6IG51bWJlcjsgZmlyc3RfbmFtZTogc3RyaW5nOyBsYXN0X25hbWU6IHN0cmluZzsgZW1haWw6IHN0cmluZzsgcm9sZTogJ2FkbWluJyB8ICd1c2VyJyB9CqFjww==)

---

Another option would be to use output schema validation/parsing. A library like [zod](https://zod.dev) could come in handy, as it omits all unknown keys by default or allows to extend existing schemas. To keep everything DRY, you could make zod the source of truth of your schemas and pass their inferred types to Kysely.

```js
import { z } from 'zod'
import { Kysely, type Generated, type Selectable } from 'kysely'
import { PlanetScaleDialect } from 'kysely-planetscale'

const userSchema = z.object({
    id: z.custom<Generated<number>>(
        (thing) => z.number().safeParse(thing).success
    ),
    first_name: z.string(),
    last_name: z.string(),
    email: z.string(),
    password: z.string(),
    is_email_verified: z.coerce.boolean(),
    role: z.enum(['admin', 'user'])
})

const safeUserSchema = userSchema.omit({ password: true }).extend({ id: z.number() })

type User = z.infer<typeof userSchema>
type SafeUser = Selectable<z.infer<typeof safeUserSchema>>

interface Database {
    user: User
}

const db = new Kysely<Database>({
  dialect: new PlanetScaleDialect({url: '<url>'})
})

const getUserById = async (id: number) => {
  const user = await db
    .selectFrom('user')
    .where('user.id', '=', id)
    .selectAll()
    .executeTakeFirst()
  return user
}

const user = await getUserById(15);

const safeUser = safeUserSchema.parse(user);
//       ^? SafeUser
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgLABQoksicA0gJ4DOApgDaMA0cMjYrOAHFWAO1ZQAhjFbEeAZQ6sAxjEkAjdoIzZcBANYsOjclXDR4SAArtJ4mPOWStAEWDOV8HTjz5DbTgBaMFt7ZictU0plCFFmeABXNihHAAtWEEk4AF4UADoIdQArTwAKBEo4KrhgYgAufOUkmFwAHhFxKRliVtEEkHUJAD4h0srqidKYVOBRAHMAShyh-L6BiVKFvOZJTFYrSSg2KZn5reYE5WVWZmZxqoWue6xgI5gAfVFJEFYG5G2YFBZnNNk8KBNbPFPt9fvl4kD5qDnhlJMB2H8AQiQY9nmBJLcAO7QepwwHApHg6rAZjvFFo94ANwkwEwwFkGJiEmueXUEAgWjsFImOC0GLE-VKAG18JJiCBZvgePgkhJ8ABdBaUNCaijRWLxOA7PYAVWSaRROTgKpSynSmQK8pg5TgeMJxIagIS2i2rAAHjJRMRnbUMWtBlBNugdZQ+AI4KaJJb-rM9lBWrHWBBMFazbaUUMY-xBPJdqwE1BLYotKoNFpWsnRKn00Ws4bS+XzZkRpRKLMZFBMJJrnAXNINPjBBVKVVrQ1y1qexQYnF4MR1JbxASGEZOK1R2p1BPRlOqsR3NWYA1N3AbHZWA4Iqw3B5VOUElB0QRWu-2EN8NqtWjJd9XgOZ73LAAhRgAEliEtfFGFEZQ4FKEM4DDCQlmyFYTzgZcDWteCCVRVd1GebYlFUAAxHxSmVZJ8B1CY8gJdIoFYOjrTyWpFQIbJeNqJjqgoi8AEF2HYTZyL9FQEhkAAVSR9FYKjXniKTKXYmB31EHMJAXXVgJXPSK1ySRiOAUDwOSKDYNKABGABWBYAG5F3w+AjTLZJLS8js83tPEjg461XMoAB6cKJmqAA9AB+IA)

Comment: This is so helpful. Thank you Igal!